# multiple forms same page ionic2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new in Ionic2 and can't solve one thing myself, I have small app width page: user-list and getting data from firebase width angularfire2.

First table name in Firebase is: imported
Second Table name in Firebase is: userProfile

in the imported table is user details (name, email, bdate etc..) and I want to get data from this table, then push to the userProfile table one by one.

so my user-list.ts is this:

```
export class UsersListPage {

  public signupForm: FormGroup;

  user:any;
  usersList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  usersTable: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    public authProvider: AuthProvider, 
    public db: AngularFireDatabase

    ) {     
    this.usersList = db.list('/imported');
    this.usersTable = db.list('usersProfile');
    this.user = authProvider.userUid(); 

    this.signupForm = formBuilder.group({
    address: [''],
    password: [''],
    bday: [''],
    email: [''],
    name: [''],
    number: [''],
    signedup: [''],
    telephone: [''],
    zip: [''],
    uid: [''],
  });


  }

createUser(){
     this.authProvider.signupUser(this.signupForm.value.email, this.signupForm.value.password).then(() => {

      this.usersTable.push({ 
        email:     this.signupForm.value.email, 
        password:  this.signupForm.value.password,
        address:   this.signupForm.value.address,
        bday:      this.signupForm.value.bday,
        name:      this.signupForm.value.name,
        number:    this.signupForm.value.number,
        signedup:  this.signupForm.value.signedup,
        telephone: this.signupForm.value.telephone,
        zip:       this.signupForm.value.zip,
        uid:       this.user     
      });

    });

}

}
```

and my html is:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <form *ngFor="let user of usersList | async" [formGroup]="signupForm" (submit)="createUser()">
      <ion-input formControlName="email" value="{{ user.email }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="password" value="{{ user.telephone }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="address" value="{{ user.address }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="bday" value="{{ user.bday }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="name" value="{{ user.name }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="number" value="{{ user.number }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="signedup" value="{{ user.signedup }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="telephone" value="{{ user.telephone }}" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-input formControlName="zip" value="{{ user.zip }}" type="hidden"></ion-input>
      <button ion-button type="submit" color="secondary" >
      User Registration
    </button>      
  </form>     

</ion-content>
```

it works but one problem is here, when I click the button only adds the last record from imported table, so I can not add one by one user per click

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 

'when I click button only adds last record from imported table, so I can not add one by one user per click', can you elaborate on this?